# CREATE TABLE is not allowed in a non-volatile function

Tags: postgresql, function, non-volatile

I have the following three tables :

```
create table drugs(
    id integer,
    name varchar(20),
    primary key(id)
);
create table prescription(
    id integer,
    drug_id integer,
    primary key(id),
    foreign key(drug_id) references drugs(id)
);
create table visits(
    patient_id varchar(10),
    prescription_id integer,
    primary key( patient_id , prescription_id),
    foreign key(prescription_id) references prescription(id)
);
```

I wrote the following function on these tables to show me a patient's drugs list(the patient id is parameter):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.patients_drugs(
    patientid character varying)
    RETURNS TABLE(drug_id integer, drug_name character varying) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    STABLE STRICT 
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
begin
    create temporary table result_table(
        drug_id integer,
        drug_name varchar(20)
    );
    return  query select distinct drug.id , drug.name 
    from  visits join prescription
    on visits.patient_id = patientID;

end;
$BODY$;
```

However, it gives me this error:

> CREATE TABLE is not allowed in a non-volatile function

Comment: Use `VOLATILE` `STRICT` instead of `STABLE` `STRICT` in your function definition.

Comment: (Also I'd recommend to place `STABLE`/`VOLATILE` and `STRICT` on two separate lines)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a table in order to be able to "return a table". Just get rid of the CREATE TABLE statement.

But your query isn't correct either, as you are selecting columns from the `drug` table, but you never include that in the `FROM` clause. You can also get rid of the `distinct` clause if you don't use a join, but an EXISTS condition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.patients_drugs(p_patientid character varying)
    RETURNS TABLE(drug_id integer, drug_name character varying) 
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $BODY$
begin
  return query 
    select d.*
    from drugs d
    where exists (select *
                  from prescription p
                    join visits v on v.prescription_id = p.id
                  where d.id = p.drug_id
                   and v.patientid = p_patientid);
end;
$BODY$;
```

Or better, use a simple SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.patients_drugs(p_patientid character varying)
    RETURNS TABLE(drug_id integer, drug_name character varying) 
    LANGUAGE sql
AS 
$BODY$
  select d.*
  from drugs d
  where exists (select *
                from prescription p
                  join visits v on v.prescription_id = p.id
                where d.id = p.drug_id
                  and v.patientid = p_patientid);
$BODY$;
```